# Fast process std::bitset<65536> in parallel

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing

Once there was a deleted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71181810/c-fast-iterate-and-modify-operations), that I wrote a huge answer to, but this question was deleted and author refused to undelete it.

So posting here a short summary of this question. And immediately answering this question myself, just to share my results.

Question was that if we're given `std::bitset<65536>` that is processed (by some formula) inside inner loop bit-by-bit, then how can we boost this computation?

Outer loop just called inner loop many times (lets say 50 000 times), and outer loop can't be processed in parallel, because each next iteration depends on results of previous iteration.

Example code of this process:

```cpp
std::bitset<65536> bits{};
uint64_t hash = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
    // Process Bits
    for (size_t j = 0; j < bits.size(); ++j)
        bits[j] = ModifyBit(i, j, hash, bits[j]);
    hash = Hash(bits, hash);
}
```

Code above is just one sample way of processing, it is not a real case. The real case is such that many times we process `std::bitset<65536>` somehow in such a way that all bits can be processed independently.

The question is how we can process bits in parallel as fast as possible inside inner loop.

One important **Note** that formula that modifies bits is generic, meaning that we don't know it in advance and can't make [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) instructions out of it.

But what we know is that all bits can be processed independently. And that we need to parallelize this processing. Also we can't parallelize outer loop as each its iteration depends on results of previous iteration.

Another **Note** is that std::bitset<65536> is quite small, just 1K of 64-bit words. So it means that directly using pool of std::thread of std::async threads will not work as each thread's work will be just around 50-200 nano-seconds, very tiny time to start and stop threads and send work to them. Even std::mutex takes 75 nano-seconds on my Windows machine (although 20 nano-seconds on Linux), so using std::mutex is also a big overhead.

One may assume that `ModifyBit()` function above takes around same time for each bit, otherwise there is no understanding on how to schedule balanced parallelization of a loop, only by slicing it into very many tiny tasks hoping that longer tasks will be balanced out by several shorter one.

Comment: Since the reason for the deletion was suspicious to me, I vote for the question to be undeleted and flag a moderator to check if this was a normal behaviour. Sorry for this incident. It can be quite frustrating to spend a lot of time helping someone that just delete the question just after receiving an answer (often students to hide their traces). Note that you can get the right to vote for undeletion at 20k reputation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks! Probably if question was deleted then it means author doesn't need it or care for it anymore. So I can easily overtake it as my question with re-phrasing it (as it contained no secret information at all), what I exactly did, and continue development on it here.

Comment: ```One important Note that formula that modifies bits is generic, meaning that we don't know it in advance and can't make SIMD instructions out of it.``` if its about looping different times per bit, it can be still vectorized but with lower efficiency, assuming no data dependency between iterations.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Actually by that statement I only meant that this question is not about how to use SIMD instruction for speeding up computation. Obviously I can do it and will, if it is possible in final problem, but this might be posted as different SO Question, if needed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented quite large and complex solution for your task, but which works very fast. On my 4-core (8 hardware threads) laptop I have `6x` times multi-core speedup compared to single threaded version (your version of code).

Main idea of solution below is to implement very fast multi core Thread-Pool for running arbitrary tasks that has small overhead. My implementation can handle up to 1-10 Million tasks per second (depending on CPU speed and cores count).

Regular way of asynchronously starting multiple tasks is through usage of [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) or just by creating [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). Both these ways are considerably slower than my own implementation. They can't give throughput of 5 Million tasks per second like my implementation gives. And your code needs millions of tasks per second to be run for good speed. That's why I implemented everything from scratch.

After fast thread pool is implemented now we can slice your 64K bitset into smaller sub-sets and process these sub-sets in parallel. I sliced 64K bitset into 16 equal parts (see `BitSize / 16` in code), you can set other amount of parts equal to power of two, but not too many, otherwise thread pool overhead will be too large. Usually it is good to slice into amount of parts that is equal to twice the amount of hardware threads (or 4 times amount of cores).

I implemented several classes in C++ code. `AtomicMutex` class uses [std::atomic_flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) in order to implement very fast replacement for mutex that is based on spin-locking approach. This AtomicMutex is used to protect queue of tasks submitted for running on thread pool.

`RingBuffer` class is based on [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and implements simple and fast queue to store any objects. It is implemented using two pointers (head and tail), pointing into vector. When new element is added to queue then tail pointer is advanced to the right, if this pointer reaches end of vector then it wraps around to 0-th position. Same way when element is taken out from queue then head pointer also advances to the right with wrap around. RingBuffer is used to store thread pool tasks.

`Queue` class is a wrapper around RingBuffer, but with AtomicMutex protection. This spin-lock mutex is used to protect simultaneous adding/taking elements to/from queue from multiple workers' threads.

`Pool` implements multi-core pool of tasks itself. It creates as many worker threads as there are CPU hardware threads (double amount of cores) minus one. Each worker thread just polls new tasks from queue and executes them immediately. Main thread adds new tasks to queue. Pool also has Wait() capability to wait till all current tasks are finished, this waiting is used as barrier to wait till whole 64K bitset is processed (all sub-parts are processed). Pool accepts any lambdas (function closures) to be run. You can see that 64K bitset sliced into smaller parts is processed by doing `pool.Emplace(lambda)` and later `pool.Wait()` is used to wait till all sub-parts are finished. Exceptions from pool workers are collected and reported to user if there is any error. When doing Wait() pool runs tasks also inside main thread not to waste one core for just waiting of tasks to finish.

Timings reported in console are done by [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) module.

There is an ability to run both versions - single-threaded (your original version) and multi-threaded using all cores. Switch between single/multi is done by passing `MultiThreaded = true` template parameter to function `ProcessBitset()`.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/vr1xEse83)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <exception>
#include <optional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <any>
#include <type_traits>

class AtomicMutex {
    class LockerC;
public:
    void lock() {
        while (f_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
            //f_.wait(true, std::memory_order_acquire)
        ;
    }
    void unlock() {
        f_.clear(std::memory_order_release);
        //f_.notify_all();
    }
    LockerC Locker() { return LockerC(*this); }
private:
    class LockerC {
    public:
        LockerC() = delete;
        LockerC(AtomicMutex & mux) : pmux_(&mux) { mux.lock(); }
        LockerC(LockerC const & other) = delete;
        LockerC(LockerC && other) : pmux_(other.pmux_) { other.pmux_ = nullptr; }
        ~LockerC() { if (pmux_) pmux_->unlock(); }
        LockerC & operator = (LockerC const & other) = delete;
        LockerC & operator = (LockerC && other) = delete;
    private:
        AtomicMutex * pmux_ = nullptr;
    };
    
    std::atomic_flag f_ = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};

template <typename T>
class RingBuffer {
public:
    RingBuffer() : buf_(1 << 8), last_(buf_.size() - 1) {}
    T & front() { return buf_[first_]; }
    T const & front() const { return buf_[first_]; }
    T & back() { return buf_[last_]; }
    T const & back() const { return buf_[last_]; }
    size_t size() const { return size_; }
    bool empty() const { return size_ == 0; }
    
    template <typename ... Args>
    void emplace(Args && ... args) {
        while (size_ >= buf_.size()) {
            std::rotate(&buf_[0], &buf_[first_], &buf_[buf_.size()]);
            first_ = 0;
            last_ = buf_.size() - 1;
            buf_.resize(buf_.size() * 2);
        }
        ++size_;
        ++last_;
        if (last_ >= buf_.size())
            last_ = 0;
        buf_[last_] = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    
    void pop() {
        if (size_ == 0)
            return;
        --size_;
        ++first_;
        if (first_ >= buf_.size())
            first_ = 0;
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> buf_;
    size_t first_ = 0, last_ = 0, size_ = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Queue {
public:
    size_t Size() const { return q_.size(); }
    bool Empty() const { return q_.size() == 0; }
    
    template <typename ... Args>
    void Emplace(Args && ... args) {
        auto lock = m_.Locker();
        q_.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    
    T Pop(std::function<void()> const & on_empty = []{},
          std::function<void()> const & on_full  = []{}) {
        while (true) {
            if (q_.empty()) {
                on_empty();
                continue;
            }
            auto lock = m_.Locker();
            if (q_.empty()) {
                on_empty();
                continue;
            }
            on_full();
            T val = std::move(q_.front());
            q_.pop();
            return std::move(val);
        }
    }
    
    std::optional<T> TryPop() {
        auto lock = m_.Locker();
        if (q_.empty())
            return std::nullopt;
        T val = std::move(q_.front());
        q_.pop();
        return std::move(val);
    }
private:
    AtomicMutex m_;
    RingBuffer<T> q_;
};

class RunInDestr {
public:
    RunInDestr(std::function<void()> const & f) : f_(f) {}
    ~RunInDestr() { f_(); }
private:
    std::function<void()> const & f_;
};

class Pool {
public:
    struct FinishExc {};
    struct Worker {
        std::unique_ptr<std::atomic<bool>> pdone = std::make_unique<std::atomic<bool>>(true);
        std::unique_ptr<std::exception_ptr> pexc = std::make_unique<std::exception_ptr>();
        std::unique_ptr<std::thread> thr;
    };
    Pool(size_t nthreads = size_t(-1)) {
        if (nthreads == size_t(-1))
            nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1;
        std::cout << "Pool has " << nthreads << " worker threads." << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
            workers_.emplace_back(Worker{});
            workers_.back().thr = std::make_unique<std::thread>(
                [&, pdone = workers_.back().pdone.get(), pexc = workers_.back().pexc.get()]{
                    try {
                        std::function<void()> f_done = [pdone]{
                            pdone->store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                        }, f_empty = [this]{
                            CheckFinish();
                        }, f_full = [pdone]{
                            pdone->store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                        };
                        while (true) {
                            RunInDestr set_done(f_done);
                            tasks_.Pop(f_empty, f_full)();
                        }
                    } catch (...) {
                        exc_.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                        *pexc = std::current_exception();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
    ~Pool() {
        Wait();
        Finish();
    }
    void CheckExc() {
        if (!exc_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
            return;
        Finish();
        throw std::runtime_error("Pool: Exception occured!");
    }
    void Finish() {
        finish_ = true;
        for (auto & w: workers_)
            try {
                w.thr->join();
                if (*w.pexc)
                    std::rethrow_exception(*w.pexc);
            } catch (FinishExc const &) {}
        workers_.clear();
    }
    template <typename ... Args>
    void Emplace(Args && ... args) {
        CheckExc();
        tasks_.Emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    void Wait() {
        while (true) {
            auto task = tasks_.TryPop();
            if (!task)
                break;
            (*task)();
        }
        
        while (true) {
            bool done = true;
            for (auto & w: workers_)
                if (!w.pdone->load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                    done = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (done)
                break;
        }
        
        CheckExc();
    }
private:
    void CheckFinish() {
        if (finish_)
            throw FinishExc{};
    }
    Queue<std::function<void()>> tasks_;
    std::vector<Worker> workers_;
    bool finish_ = false;
    std::atomic<bool> exc_ = false;
};

template <bool MultiThreaded = true, size_t BitSize>
void ProcessBitset(Pool & pool, std::bitset<BitSize> & bset,
        std::string const & businessLogicCriteria) {
    static size_t constexpr block = BitSize / 16;
    for (int j = 0; j < BitSize; j += block) {
        auto task = [&bset, j]{
            int const hi = std::min(j + block, BitSize);
            for (int i = j; i < hi; ++i) {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    bset[i] = 0;
                else
                    bset[i] = 1;
            }
        };
        if constexpr(MultiThreaded)
            pool.Emplace(std::move(task));
        else
            task();
    }
    if constexpr(MultiThreaded)
        pool.Wait();
}

static auto const gtb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

double Time() {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - gtb).count();
}

void Compute() {
    Pool pool;
    
    std::bitset<65536> bset;
    std::string businessLogicCriteria;
    
    int const hi = 50000;
    for (int j = 0; j < hi; ++j) {
        if ((j & 0x1FFF) == 0 || j + 1 >= hi)
            std::cout << j / 1000 << "K (" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << Time() << " sec), " << std::flush;
        ProcessBitset(pool, bset, businessLogicCriteria);
        businessLogicCriteria = "...";
    }
}

void TimeMeasure() {
    size_t constexpr A = 1 << 16, B = 1 << 5;
    {
        Pool pool;
        auto const tb = Time();
        int64_t volatile x = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < A; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < B; ++j)
                pool.Emplace([&]{ x = x + 1; });
            pool.Wait();
        }
        std::cout << "AtomicPool time " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << (Time() - tb)
            << " sec, speed " << A * B / (Time() - tb) / 1000.0 << " empty K-tasks/sec, "
            << 1'000'000 / (A * B / (Time() - tb)) << " sec/M-task, no-collisions "
            << std::setprecision(7) << double(x) / (A * B) << std::endl;
    }
    
    {
        auto const tb = Time();
        //size_t const nthr = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        size_t constexpr C = A / 8;
        std::vector<std::future<void>> asyncs;
        int64_t volatile x = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < C; ++i) {
            asyncs.clear();
            for (size_t j = 0; j < B; ++j)
                asyncs.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ x = x + 1; }));
            asyncs.clear();
        }
        std::cout << "AsyncPool time " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << (Time() - tb)
            << " sec, speed " << C * B / (Time() - tb) / 1000.0 << " empty K-tasks/sec, "
            << 1'000'000 / (C * B / (Time() - tb)) << " sec/M-task, no-collisions "
            << std::setprecision(7) << double(x) / (C * B) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        TimeMeasure();
        Compute();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Unknown Exception!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output for 4 cores (8 hardware threads):

```
Pool has 7 worker threads.
AtomicPool time 0.903 sec, speed 2321.831 empty K-tasks/sec, 0.431 sec/M-task, no-collisions 0.9999967
AsyncPool time 0.982 sec, speed 266.789 empty K-tasks/sec, 3.750 sec/M-task, no-collisions 0.9999123
Pool has 7 worker threads.
0K (0.074 sec), 8K (0.670 sec), 16K (1.257 sec), 24K (1.852 sec), 32K (2.435 sec), 40K (2.984 sec), 49K (3.650 sec), 49K (3.711 sec),
```

For comparison below is single-threaded version timings, that is `6x` times slower:

```
0K (0.125 sec), 8K (3.786 sec), 16K (7.754 sec), 24K (11.202 sec), 32K (14.662 sec), 40K (18.056 sec), 49K (21.470 sec), 49K (21.841 sec),
```

Comment: This assumes each chunk of bits takes the same time to compute. If not then you need to user more chunks to balance it better. Maybe even use work stealing queues to rebalance work when one thread runs out of data to process early.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes, in case of my solution simplest would be just to slice it into more chunks. I measured timings with 16 chunks of 65536 bits. And even with 32 chunks speed is still not much influenced by Queue overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You have this inner loop you want to parallelize:

```cpp
for (size_t j = 0; j < bits.size(); ++j)
    bits[j] = ModifyBit(i, j, hash, bits[j]);
```

So a good idea is to split it into chunks, and have multiple threads do each chunk in parallel. You can submit chunks to workers easily with a `std::atomic<int>` counter that increments to identify which chunk to work on. You can also make sure the threads all stop working after one loop before starting the next with a [`std::barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier):

```cpp
std::bitset<65536> bits{};

std::thread pool[8];  // Change size accordingly
std::atomic<int> task_number{0};
constexpr std::size_t tasks_per_loop = 32;  // Arbitrarily chosen
constexpr std::size_t block_size = (bits.size()+tasks_per_loop-1) / tasks_per_loop;

// (only written to by one thread by the barrier, so not atomic)
uint64_t hash = 0;
int i = 0;

std::barrier barrier(std::size(pool), [&]() {
    task_number = 0;
    ++i;
    hash = Hash(bits, hash);
});

for (std::thread& t : pool) {
    t = std::thread([&]{
        while (i < 50000) {
            for (int t; (t = task_number++) < tasks_per_loop;) {
                int block_start = t * block_size;
                int block_end = std::min(block_start + block_size, bits.size());
                for (int j = block_start; j < block_end; ++j) {
                    bits[j] = ModifyBit(i, j, hash, bits[j]);
                }
            }

            // Wait for other threads to finish and hash
            // to be calculated before starting next loop
            barrier.arrive_and_wait();
        }
    });
}

for (std::thread& t : pool) t.join();
```

(The seemingly easy way of parallelizing the for loop with OpenMP `#pragma omp parallel for` seemed slower with some testing, perhaps because the tasks were so small)

Here it is against your implementation running similar code: https://godbolt.org/z/en76Kv4nn

And on my machine, running this a few times with 1 million iterations took 28 to 32 seconds with my approach and 44 to 50 seconds with your general thread pool approach (granted this is much less general because it can't execute arbitrary `std::function<void()>` tasks).

Comment: Thanks for this very simple and great-working idea of using atomic counter for lightweight spreading tasks among workers! Certainly it should be faster than mine approach because I'm doing similar stuff but for very general task of running any `std::function<void()>`. Exactly this problem of processing bitset of course is faster with atomic only.I modified your godbolt link a bit to place both solutions into exactly same condition - 32 sub-tasks and threads equal to number of cores minus one, also I added output of number of threads to console.[Here it is](https://godbolt.org/z/enz8K3T7P),code

Comment: Continuing on previous comment. Your solution is faster than mine by exactly 10% of time on my old 1.5 GHz laptop with 4 cores with hyper-threading (8 hardware threads), [here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEDrd.png) output of my console (see number of threads in brackets after pool type). Atomic counter spreading of tasks is definitely faster, but total time is not MUCH faster probably due to std::barrier, which is probably not atomic-based, but does some thread-sleeping logic, probably we can rewrite it using atomics too to make it faster.

Comment: You can simply launch 100 threads on a 4 core cpu and let OS do the load balancing with the cost of context-switching but can't beat a load-balancer like this atomic version but still can beat single-thread and non-balanced 4 threads (like some mandelbrot surface fully reciding  in 1 thread and all empty pixels in other threads, etc...).